# it's posible add a new service into a stack in docker without update the .yml document?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-stack

I'm trying to add to a deployed docker stack a new service without update the .yml document

my code is

`docker stack deploy -c app.yml app`

Add a new service

`docker service create --name app_newservice --network app_network app_image:0.1`

To visualise if the stack add the new service i run

`docker stack services app`

But after i run my commands, i can interact with my new added container because is in the same network, but is not listed in the same stack, the problem is i dont know if my stack is well admistrated by the swarm

https://i.stack.imgur.com/V47oK.png

app_nginx................. app

app_otherservice...... app

app_newservice........ ----

app_portainer........... app

I spect the new service listed into the stack. It's posible?

Answer (score 1):

Well it can't be. it's completely needed update the full .yml to correctly update the stack.